# How to Update multiple records of a table based on result set of many subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to update 10 rows and   3 fields of table "Contract"

Each 10 row have to be updated with different value.

```
   update  contract_equipment_purchase   set date_shipped = (
    select lat.tstamp from lease_asset la join CR983_TMP  tmp on la.serial_num=tmp.serial  join 
         (select lease_asset_id ,max(tstamp) as tstamp from lease_asset_transaction where status='Placed' group by lease_asset_id)
             lat on la.id=lat.lease_asset_id join lease_asset_status las on las.id=la.id and las.status<>'Out of Service' ),
lease_asset_id= (
        select la.id from lease_asset la join CR983_TMP  tmp on la.serial_num=tmp.serial  join 
             lease_asset_status las on las.id=la.id and las.status<>'Out of Service' ),
comprehensive_expiration_date='2013-10-31'
     where id_contract in (
        select cep.id_contract from contract_equipment_purchase cep join contract c on cep.id_contract =c.id_contract and c.id_contract_type=10 
            join facilities f on f.id=c.id_facility
            join CR983_TMP crtmp on crtmp.account=f.accounting_id);
```

the main issue i am facing is all sub queries give multiple result as i have to update multiple rows with different values. 
How can i do that ?

Comment: Please post your intended `WHERE` clause in the subqueries

Comment: sql updated with where !

Answer (score 1):

this syntax should give you what you're looking for

```
update contract
set contract.account = s.account,
shipitem = i.item,
date='2013-3-25'
from contract c
  inner join shippertable s on c.account = s.account
  inner join itemtable i on c.item = i.item
where contractname = (select name from customers where)
```

Comment: If instead of "inner join shippertable s on c.account = s.account"    it is  "inner join shippertable s on c.account = (select s.account from customer where ..)   "    and this subquery return multiple records ,  will it work ? or i have to use WITH ?